# Проверка на уникальность email с помощью Js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма регистрации и в ней ипнут, который на вход принимает email пользователя:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
```

Есть инпут который сохраняет все email в переменную.

```
<input type='hidden' id="emailValid" value='
    <?
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "project");
        $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM users");

        while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
              echo $row['email'] . '<br>';
         }
     ?>
'>
```

Получаю оба результата в js коде:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var emailValid = $('#emailValid').val();
```

Как мне сравнить введенный email с теми что есть в базе, и в случае если такая почта уже есть в базе, вывести ошибку? Может есть другие способы, а то я не уверен в правильности своего кода и что вообще так делают.

Comment: Ужас-то какой, за то, что вы сливаете список всех емейлов всем в открытую, вас побьют

Comment: @andreymal, это только для себя, чтобы понять все ли работает правильно

Comment: Сейчас бы напрямую со страницы авторизацию делать, открытым запросом. Серверная часть в помощь, считываешь с поля значения -> передаешь post запросом -> обрабатываешь в серверной части -> возвращаешь результат!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну такое себе решение. Используйте **AJAX**. 
Сначала напишите php скрипт который будет проверять уникальность email`а, потом обращайтесь к нему через AJAX-запрос.

К примеру php: `validator.php`

```
  if(isset($_POST['email']){
    /*Какой-то код проверки емейла из $_POST['email'] на уникальность*/ 

    /*Если емейл уникален делаем*/
    return 0;

    /*В обратном случае*/
    return 1;
  }
```

И делаем запрос к этому скрипту

```js
$('form').submmit(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "validator.php",
  data: "email="+$('#email').val(),
  success: function(data){
    if($data == 0)
      alert('Email уникален');
    else
      alert('Email не уникален');
  }
});

return false;

});
```

```html
<form>

<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">

<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```